# Costumer custom attribute bulk fill script

Tags: magento-1.9

I've installed an extension that separate normal person information from enterprise information.

the taxvat field is still used by normal person but enterprises have to fill a new field and specify that the cliente is an enterprise.

The problem is: for new users ok, no problem but old enteprises clients are having problems because the new extension says the "taxvat" number is wrong. It's right because the taxvat number format are different among person and enterprises.

I moved all information from taxvat to this new field but I still need to specify the these clients are enterprise by filling a field called "tipopessoa"

My question is: Is there a way to make a script to do it?

I need that all clients that have the patern 0001 on cnpj field have the field tipopessoa filled with "Jurídica"